# iTunes Connect - Connect existing account to iTunes Connect as a developer

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have my own iTunes Connect Account and Apple developer license.

Now I joined and existing developer Team and want to be able to upload builds for them to iTunes Connect.

I got added via developer.apple.com with my existing developer account email, and assigned the role "Administrator". This worked well. But now it's not possible to add this existing account to the company's iTunes Connect.

If I add myself with another email address, I can not upload builds, as this new email does not have a Apple Developer subscription.

What do I do to be able to upload builds to iTunesConnect with my existing developer account?

Answer (score 0):

I have this situation and I have to upload builds using [Application Loader](https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/).  There you can log in directly with your iTunes Connect email address without it complaining that you're not a registered developer.  Perform the archive in Xcode and then export the app for the App Store.  From Application Loader, find the .ipa file on your computer and upload it.